# Refresh page after update looping.. div better?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a page where i'm using edit-in-place... now, after the update it's showing slashes even though I am using stripslashes() - prob because ajax call just updating the div therefore bypassing the stripslashes function

Anyway, if i refresh the page manually they go away, which is what I need... so, i figure if i add a page refresh after the mysql update then all should be good - but i seem to be getting caught in endless loop

this is the php which is called within the jquery edit-in-place function:

```
$update = $_POST['update_value'];

$div_id = $_POST['element_id'];

include '/dbconnect.inc';

$changedata = mysql_query("
update page_content set 
div_content_old = div_content,
div_content = '$update'
where div_id = '$div_id'",$db);

//echo $_POST['update_value']; commented out as before header()

header("Location: $PHP_SELF"); // using php_self as called from various pages
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't see a loop in your code - please post the complete code. did you add debug printing ? javascript "alert" to see where it fails ?

Comment: You should figure out why it is showing the slashes... especially since you are expecting them not to show.

Comment: @afuzzyllama I am trying believe me, it's also adding masses of whitespace before and after the string and trim() isn't killing that either... puzzling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing question as it seems there's actually a bug in the js code which was forcing me to try this.

What i did in the end was simply stripslashes() before the result of the function was actually echoed - thanks for looking guys!